# How to upload a data including "timestamp" in postgres

Tags: postgresql, analysis

I am using Postgres, but every time when I try to upload data including timestamp type to one of its columns, Postgres gives me this error message :

ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "21/04/2020 18:19"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY get_safe, line 2, column joined_getsafe_at: "21/04/2020 18:19"

how to upload the data including timestamp type successfully in Postgres?

Comment: What does `SHOW datestyle` return? Your string "21/04/2020 18:19" seems to not be recognized as a date/timestamp.

Comment: Use ISO format strings: `2020-04-21 18:19:00`